# Variable substitution in SQLite Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following Python code and it gives me errors when I execute it, the error says

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

```py
statement = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES " % (table,columns) + "(%s,%s,%s);"
cur.execute(statement, (index,fullpath,filename))
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL parameters are handled by the database, not by Python, so the syntax is not necessarily the same as Python's.

In SQLite (and most other databases), parameters are marked with a `?`:

```py
statement = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (?,?,?);" % (table,columns)
cur.execute(statement, (index,fullpath,filename))
```

Comment: thank you it worked, replacing the +"(%s,%s,%s);" with ? did the trick